# CakePHP 3 - DB table assocciation with itself

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-3.0, model-associations

I have a table in my DB that has a association with itself. I am trying to get all parent categories with their child categories, but I can't get it to work.

This is how the table looks:

```
id | name | description | image | is_child | forum_category_id | level
```

Now, obviously the "forum_category_id" is the parent id that refers to the same table.

I baked the model and this is in the table file:

```
$this->belongsTo('ForumCategories', [
    'foreignKey' => 'forum_category_id'
]);
$this->hasMany('ForumCategories', [
    'foreignKey' => 'forum_category_id'
]);
```

The code I use to load from DB is this:

```
debug($results = $this->find()
    ->order(['id' => 'ASC'])
    ->where(['is_child' => 0])
    ->toArray()
);
```

With this code, I do get the parent categories, but not the children.
So I thought to use "Contain", but that only returns empty parent categories.

```
debug($results = $this->find()
    ->order(['id' => 'ASC'])
    ->where(['is_child' => 0])
    ->contain([
        'ForumCategories' => function ($q)
        {
            return $q
                ->where(['is_child' => 1]);
        }
    ])
    ->toArray()
);
```

I have no idea how to get the child categories. I read something about using "Threaded" (no results/success so far) or the TreeBehaviour, but I don't really any idea on how to use them.

Any idea on how this is still possible is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You should use different aliases for the 2 association.

```
$this->belongsTo('ForumCategories', [
    'foreignKey' => 'forum_category_id'
]);
$this->hasMany('ForumChildCategories', [
    'className' => 'ForumCategories',
    'foreignKey' => 'forum_category_id'
]);
```

By this `$this->ForumCategories->find()` will give you the parent and `$this->ForumChilfCategories->find()` the children.

Otherwise - if that is option - change your database schema and use tree behaviour.

Comment: What should we do if we want to fetch children at n level, I have tried by adding 'recursive' => -1, but it does not work.

Comment: `recursive` is removed in CakePHP 3. Check the new query builder https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html