# CakePHP3 Linking Table Together in Same Model (Inner Join)

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

i've a table named 'customers' with following (shortened) schema:

```
id | customer_id | type | salutation | forename | surname | created | modified
```

In this table, I want to store people, which are may be associated:

```
id | customer_id | type    | salutation | forename | surname | created             | modified
 1 | NULL        | husband | Mr.        | John     | Doe     | 2016-01-05 10:00:00 | 2016-01-05 10:00:00
 2 |  1          | wife    | Mrs.       | Jane     | Doe     | 2016-01-05 10:01:00 | 2016-01-05 10:01:00
 3 |  1          | child   | Mr.        | Jim      | Doe     | 2016-01-05 10:02:00 | 2016-01-05 10:02:00
```

Customers with "customer_id" = NULL are the master customers, but #2 and #3 refers to #1.

I've created the table in phpmyadmin and do:
"bin/cake bake all customers" without errors.
Then I created the 'master customer'. When I create the second account, I expect that the select-field shows customer #1, but the dropdown-field is empty.

The model:

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->table('customers');
    $this->displayField('id');
    $this->primaryKey('id');

    $this->belongsTo('Customers', [
        'foreignKey' => 'customer_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('Customers', [
        'foreignKey' => 'customer_id'
    ]);
}
```

If you need further information or more piece of code, let me know.
Many thanks in advance.

best regards
Martin

---

**SQL to reproduce**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customers` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `typ` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `customer_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `salutation` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  `prename` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `surname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `customers` (`id`, `typ`, `customer_id`, `salutation`, `prename`, `surname`, `created`, `modified`) VALUES
(1, 'husband', NULL, 'Mr.', 'John', 'Doe', '2016-03-02 21:26:32', '2016-03-02 21:26:32'),
(2, 'wife', 1, 'Ms.', 'Jane', 'Doe', '2016-03-02 21:27:25', '2016-03-02 22:10:05'),
(3, 'child', 1, 'Mr.', 'Jim', 'Doe', '2016-03-02 21:27:41', '2016-03-02 22:10:15');

ALTER TABLE `customers` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`), ADD KEY `customers_fk0` (`customer_id`);
ALTER TABLE `customers` MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=4;
ALTER TABLE `customers` ADD CONSTRAINT `customers_fk0` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customers` (`id`);
```

Than, run

```
bin/cake bake all customers
```

---

**EDIT**
I've checked, the [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31319820), and changed my model

```
$this->belongsTo('Customers', [
    'foreignKey' => 'customer_id',
    'joinType' => 'INNER'
]);
$this->hasMany('ChildCustomers', [ // <-- changed this line
    'className' => 'Customers',    // <-- added this line
    'foreignKey' => 'customer_id'
]);
```

Now, if I try to add/edit, no changes to the select. But if I view an existing customer, i got:

> Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not
>   unique table/alias: 'Customers'

This is the code for displaying the select:

```
echo $this->Form->input('customer_id');
```

This code was genereated by "bin/cake bake all customers"

---

**EDIT 2**

I'll will summarize my current state:

Model:

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->table('customers');
    $this->displayField('id');
    $this->primaryKey('id');

    $this->belongsTo('ParentCustomers', [
        'className' => 'Customers',
        'foreignKey' => 'customer_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('ChildCustomers', [
        'className' => 'Customers',
        'foreignKey' => 'customer_id'
    ]);
}

public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
{
    $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['customer_id'], 'ParentCustomers'));
    return $rules;
}
```

Controller:

```
public function view($id = null)
{
    $customer = $this->Customers->get($id, [
        'contain' => ['ParentCustomers']
    ]);

    $this->set('customer', $customer);
    $this->set('_serialize', ['customer']);
}
```

If an user has an association (wife, child), the view displays a headline "Related Customers" on bottom of the page, but no additional table which shows the related customers. If an user has "customer_id = 0", the view said 'Record not found in table "customers"'.

I've also added

```
$this->set('customers', $this->Customers->find('list'));
```

to the add() and edit() function, but I found no way to allow also an empty value.

For clarification:
Later, the front page (index()) should only list the "master customer" with customer_id = 0 with a small nested table, if he have a wife and/or children.

I think I am on the right way... Am I?

Thanks again in Advance

Comment: Where is your code for populating the dropdown?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CakePHP 3 - DB table assocciation with itself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31319820/cakephp-3-db-table-assocciation-with-itself)

Comment: I've edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the issue by using [CakePHPs TreeBehavior](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/tree.html).

I use parent_id instead of customer_id and added rght and lft column as discribed in [Blog Tutorial - Part 3](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/part-three.html).

It is working for me now! Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You should also use `ParentCustomers` for the first association. `Customers` duplicates itself.

```
$this->belongsTo('ParentCustomers', [ // <-- You need to change here
    'className' => 'Customers', // <-- You need to change here
    'foreignKey' => 'customer_id',
    'joinType' => 'INNER'
]);
$this->hasMany('ChildCustomers', [
    'className' => 'Customers',
    'foreignKey' => 'customer_id'
]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your hint, but it still doesn't work.
My Model looks exactly like your code snippet.
If I call domain.com/view/2, I got "Customers is not associated with Customers". The 'new' and 'edit' screen show my no error, but the select field is still empty.

Comment: The error means that you are trying to use a non-associated table. As you changed associations correctly, your `Customers` is no longer associated with `Customers`. You need to use  `ParentCustomers` or `ChildCustomers` instead. `$this->Customers->contain('ParentCustomers')` or what not.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand, what you're trying to tell me.
How must the code look like, that I am able to choose another customer while adding or editing a customer? Many thanks in advance

Comment: [1] You need to chagne `'contain' => ['Customers']` to `'contain' => ['ParentCustomers']` in your view(). That is I wanted to say in my previous comment. 
[2] You need to chagne `$rules->existsIn(['customer_id'], 'Customers')` to `$rules->existsIn(['customer_id'], 'ParentCustomers')` in the buildRules() method of your CustomersTable class.
[3] You need to call `$this->set('customers', $this->Customers->find('list'));` in your add()/edit() action to fill the select box.

Comment: Thanks again, I think I am on the right way... Some things work now... I've updated the question with edit2

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you did load the model already in the controller?

Put following into controller's `initialize()`: `$this->loadModel('Customers');`

EDIT: So it's like:

```
    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();

        $this->loadModel('Customers');
    }
```

Comment: Mh, I've added this to my CustomersController, but the messages/errors are still the same. I should use condition, maybe.